# Require at least one checkbox with Parsley

Tags: parsley.js

I need to force the user to check at least one checkbox with different names with parsley.

With the same name it works :

```
<label for="hobbies">Hobbies:</label>
<p>
    Skiing <input name="hobbies[]" id="hobby1" value="ski" data-parsley-required type="checkbox"><br>
    Running <input name="hobbies[]" id="hobby2" value="run" type="checkbox"><br>
    Eating <input name="hobbies[]" id="hobby3" value="eat" type="checkbox"><br>
    Sleeping <input name="hobbies[]" id="hobby4" value="sleep" type="checkbox"><br>
    Reading <input name="hobbies[]" id="hobby5" value="read" type="checkbox"><br>
    Coding <input name="hobbies[]" id="hobby6" value="code" type="checkbox"><br>
</p>
```

But with different name it doesn't :

```
<label for="hobbies">Hobbies :</label>
<p>
    Skiing <input name="hobbies1" id="hobby1" value="ski" data-parsley-required type="checkbox"><br>
    Running <input name="hobbies2" id="hobby2" value="run" type="checkbox"><br>
    Eating <input name="hobbies3" id="hobby3" value="eat" type="checkbox"><br>
    Sleeping <input name="hobbies4" id="hobby4" value="sleep" type="checkbox"><br>
    Reading <input name="hobbies5" id="hobby5" value="read" type="checkbox"><br>
    Coding <input name="hobbies6" id="hobby6" value="code" type="checkbox"><br>
</p>
```

Is there a way to manage this with data-parsley-group or something ?

note : the list of input can be long

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make them related by giving them the same `data-parsley-multiple` value.

Other possibility is to write a custom validator, [something like this](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html).

Answer (score 1):

Require at least one checkbox with Parsley:

**data-parsley-required data-parsley-mincheck="1"**

[Parsley docs on this](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/)

```
<label for="hobbies">Hobbies (Required, 1 minimum):</label>
<p>
  Skiing <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobby1" value="ski" data-parsley-required data-parsley-mincheck="1"><br>
  Running <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobby2" value="run"><br>
  Eating <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobby3" value="eat"><br>
  Sleeping <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobby4" value="sleep"><br>
  Reading <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobby5" value="read"><br>
  Coding <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="hobby6" value="code"><br>
</p>
```

Note: This depends on name for each being the same. Otherwise you can use data-parsley-multiple to link the checkboxes by name prefix. See: http://jsfiddle.net/s7xnt02e/